# How should I throw exceptions in a php auth class?

Tags: php, exception

When throwing exceptions in the following auth class example is it recommended to throw a different exception for each situation to be handled, eg:

```
addUser(...) {

    // normal database code here...

    switch(TRUE) {
        case ($username_exists):
            throw new UserExists('Cannot create new account. Account username ' . $un . ' already exists.');
        case ($email_exists):
            throw new EmailExists('Cannot create new account. Account email ' . $email . ' already exists.');
    }
}

   //to be called externally by...

try {
    $auth->adduser(...);
} catch (UserExists) {
    $output = 'That username is already taken.';
} catch (EmailExists) {
    $output = 'That email is already being used.';
} catch (AuthException $e) {
    $output = $e->getMessage();
}

echo $output;
}
```

or is it recommended to throw a general "type" of exception with a unique exception code? eg...

```
addUser(...) {

    // normal database code here...

    switch(TRUE) {
        case ($username_exists):
            throw new AuthException('Cannot create new account. Account username ' . $un . ' already exists.', 10);
        case ($email_exists):
            throw new AuthException('Cannot create new account. Account email ' . $email . ' already exists.', 20);
    }
}

   //to be called externally by...

try {
    $auth->adduser(...);
} catch (AuthException $e) {
    switch($e->getCode()) {
        case 10:
            $output = 'That username is already taken.';
            break;
        case 20:
            $output = 'That email is already being used.';
            break;
        default:
            $output = $e->getMessage();
    }
echo $output;
}
```

I ask because I'm new to exceptions and both solutions seem equally viable. Perhaps there are other solutions entirely?

**Interesting side-note:** I didn't realize I was asking a "what's your preference" question until after receiving a few answers. I anticipated a single recommended method.

Comment: You do not need the `break;` after each `throw` - the code stops executing after the `throw` and returns back to the calling-code, in your case inside the `try/catch` block.

Comment: @newfurniturey You are correct. I didn't even notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say one way is right and one way is wrong - and asking a "is this way recommended versus this way" can easily stir up a large pot if the question hits the right nerve in a large group.

Regarding your question specifically, both are valid and acceptable ways to throw different types of exceptions - and I've seen both quite frequently.

In large-scale applications in just about every language, however, I see the bottom method more often than not - and it's also my own personal style/preference. I think that throwing a single "type" of exception, `AuthException`, and specifying an exception-code is very clear and concise.

If you want it to be more descriptive (from a programming standpoint), you can use an pseudo-`enum`* setup for the codes to give a user-friendly description:

```
class AuthExceptionCode {
    const USER_EXISTS = 0;
    const EMAIL_EXISTS= 1;
    // ....
}
```

To throw the exception with the code:

```
throw new AuthException('error message', AuthExceptionCode::USER_EXISTS);
```

If you have an actual custom-`Exception` class, i.e. - you `extend Exception`, you can place the codes direction in the class itself:

```
class AuthException extends Exception {
    const MISC = -1;
    const USER_EXISTS = 0;
    const EMAIL_EXISTS= 1;

    public function __construct($message, $code = self::MISC) {
        switch ($code) {
            case self::USER_EXISTS:
                // example on how to access the codes from within the class
                // ...
```

* `Enumerations` are not native to PHP, so using `const` is the easiest method (without using a 3rd-party class/plugin.

Comment: There's no reason to create a new class to put the constants in.  Put them directly in the `AuthException` class.  Also, by convention, constants are all uppercase.

Comment: @drrcknlsn Was modifying my answer as you posted =P; In PHP - uppercase constants are the *norm*, but not in all languages (like C#, for instance). I forgot what language I was writing in for a minute - but I've updated to reflect. The irony, however, is that the OP is asking a "what's your preference" question ;)

Comment: Cool. :-)  Just an FYI - in PHP, you can't throw anything that doesn't ultimately inherit from `Exception`, and you must always define a class before using it (exceptions are no exception, hehe), so I think it's a little misleading to say _"If you have an actual custom-`Exception` class, i.e. - you `extend Exception` [...]"_, because this will always be the case.  And +1 for a more thorough answer than mine. :-P

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think the best practice is that an exception should encompass a single exceptional condition.  Take the SPL exceptions, for example.  Would you throw `InvalidUserArgumentException` and `InvalidEmailArgumentException`?  Nope.  You'd throw the SPL `InvalidArgumentException` and just change the exception message based on the details (e.g. "Invalid user" or "Invalid email").  That said, IMHO, you should use a single `AuthException` and just vary the message (like you did in your 2nd example), only instead of using codes and a switch, just output the exception message directly:

```
try {
    $auth->adduser(...);
} catch (AuthException $e) {
    $output = $e->getMessage();
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: While I agree with this philosophy, in practice if I want to use this same class throughout a project, yet output each message selectively, I don't see how I could do so.  For example, if while catching an `AuthException` for an existing username and I want one page to display the username, yet another page to display a redirection link elsewhere.

Comment: If you mean branching code based on the different conditions, then that's what codes are for and you should keep the codes.  This wasn't part of your original question, which is why I suggested removing them for brevity.  If that's not what you meant, then I have no idea what you're talking about. :-P

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the top way where you have a separate catch statement for each exception that can occur, but it depends.. If you find yourself have really long exception class names where it's difficult to understand their meaning, then I would group them up a bit.